# Google App Engine: " jdbc:google:mysql:// " not supports utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, jdbc, google-cloud-sql

- **The issue:** `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException`
- **The conditions:**

1. Target: Google cloud MySQL database.
2. Source: Google Cloud App Engine.
3. Using vpc-access-connector.
4. Using `jdbc:google:mysql://`.
5. Database and tables sets to be `utf8mb4` character.
6. Sending emojies `utf8mb4`.

- **Comment:** but everything is ok when I am when I am using my eclipse local App Engine to connect to the same clod MySQL by using `jdbc:mysql://`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using a socket connection by HikariCP as it shown in [Google document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/samples/cloud-sql-mysql-servlet-create)
and then set character utf8 by adding this two configurations:

```
config.addDataSourceProperty("characterEncoding","utf8");
config.addDataSourceProperty("useUnicode","true");
```